# Как удалить при сборке gradle файл из jar, которого изначально в проекте нет

Tags: java, gradle

В формируемом с помощью gradle jar есть файл в директории META-INF есть файл BC1024KE.SF. Нужно, чтобы его не было. Как его удалить?

Пробую

```
jar { exclude("META-INF/BC1024KE.SF") }
```

Файл остаётся на месте. Этого файла изначально в проекте нет, его добавляет автоматически одна из библиотек ('com.codeborne:selenide:'4.12.3')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jar{
//...
    doFirst {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

     exclude 'META-INF/BC1024KE.SF'
}
```